# How can I merge two dataframes based on the values on the ID variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have this two datasets

```
df = data.frame(ID = 1:10, Num = 101:110)
g = data.frame(ID = 2:6, Num = 112:116)
```

I wish that df becomes as follows by merging g into f

```
   ID Num
1   1 101
2   2 112
3   3 113
4   4 114
5   5 115
6   6 116
7   7 107
8   8 108
9   9 109
10 10 110
```

When using rows_update for the following two dataframes

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = c(1,rep(2,5),7:10), Num = c(111,rep(15,5),112:115))

g1 = data.frame(ID = rep(2,5), Num = rep(16,5))

rows_update(df1 , g1 )
```

the output is

```
Matching, by = "ID"
Error in `rows_update()`:
! `y` key values must be unique.
ℹ The following rows contain duplicate key values: `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::rows_update(df1, g1)
 2. dplyr:::rows_update.data.frame(df1, g1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rows_update`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_update(df, g)
```

-output

```
   ID Num
1   1 101
2   2 112
3   3 113
4   4 114
5   5 115
6   6 116
7   7 107
8   8 108
9   9 109
10 10 110
```

Answer (score 1):

From `df` you want to exclude those that are `%in%` `g` before `merge`ing.

```
merge(df[!df$ID %in% g$ID, ], g, all=TRUE)
#    ID Num
# 1   1 101
# 2   2 112
# 3   3 113
# 4   4 114
# 5   5 115
# 6   6 116
# 7   7 107
# 8   8 108
# 9   9 109
# 10 10 110
```